# RxJs - Multiple subscribers waiting on the same result of a promise

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

How do I get multiple subscribers waiting the same promise to resolve if it is already inflight with latecomers given a new resolution?

```
doSomething = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random(), 1000)
  })
}

// how to define obs?

obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // 0.39458743297857473
obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // 0.39458743297857473
obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // 0.39458743297857473

setTimeout(() => obs.subscribe(v => console.log(v)), 2000); // 0.9485769395265746
```

I'd like the observable to remain cold until the first subscriber, then go cold again after the result is streamed to all subsequent concurrent subscribers. I basically don't want any concurrent requests to the same underlying function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) as the creation-operator and then [`share`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) the stream:

```
doSomething = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random(), 1000));
  });
}

const obs = Rx.Observable
    .defer(doSomething)
    .share();

obs.subscribe(console.log); // resolve #1
obs.subscribe(console.log); // resolve #1
obs.subscribe(console.log); // resolve #1

setTimeout(() => obs.subscribe(console.log), 2000); // resolve #2
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works for the example I gave, so I've accepted. Many thanks for your help. I actually tried that earlier and it doesn't for for my actual use case, as opposed to the example I gave to simplify things. I see now why it doesn't work though, It's not reentrant. At the end of the pipeline that uses obs, there is library code that subscribes and in it's onNext block, it was generating an action that....drumroll...relied on obs and so deadlocked. I don't know how I always end up with these bloody horrible edge cases! :-)